# Java paint method show error

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I am working in swing based project I want to print `JTable`. For this purpose when I write print method like `(tb1.print(JTable.printMode.Normal,header,footer))` it show error that (method paint cannot be applied to given type and required Graphics and also found printMode,MessageFormat,MessageFormat) while i cannot found `PrintMode`,`MessageFormat` etc now guide me where i found such type of format while my net-bean only show `print (Graphics)`or `print(Graphics all)`? Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.MessageFormat.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.text.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*; 

public class Printing extends javax.swing.JPanel {
 public Printing() {
  initComponents();
 }

 private void tb1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("dd");
  MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page(0,number,integer)");
  try {
   tb1.paint(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, footer, header);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.format("Can not print %%n", e.getMessage()); 
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    new Printing().setVisible(true);
   }
  });
 }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please copy and paste the exact error you receive when running the program

Comment: At this line(tb1.paint(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,footer,header); i got such type of error (method paint in class component can not be applied at given type required graphics0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tb1.paint(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, footer, header);` isn't
`tb1.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, footer, header);`

Comment: Yes its mistake but now i replace paint to print but same error again?

Comment: Sir please guide me or share any link for printing receipt in java i want to print receipt for customer in which item entry with date,price,and with serial number thanks a lot.

Comment: At time being i have not attached any printer i am just want to test i design this application for any shopkeeper who want to print receipt for their customer about bill including its serial no item list,date etc please guide me or share any link thanks.